# Angular table to json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have static table

```
<table class="table" at-table at-list="List">
        <tr>
            <td at-attribute="name"  >Date and Time of Incident</td>
            <td at-attribute="values">{{info.dt}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td at-attribute="name"  >Reported By</td>
            <td at-attribute="values">{{info.reportedby}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td at-attribute="name"  >Company of Reporter</td>
            <td at-attribute="values">{{info.company}}</td>
        </tr>
<table>
```

how to create following Json from this table?

```
{"fields":[

 {"name":"Date and Time of Incident","values":["2013-05-13T15:40:00"]},

 {"name":"Reported By","values":["John Doe"]},

 {"name":"Company of Reporter","values":["CompanyA"]}]
}
```

Directive angular-table https://github.com/samu/angular-table cannot collect information in object List

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little confused by what you're asking but why don't you put the data into an array on the controller and then use Angular's ngRepeat function in the HTML?

controller.js

```
$scope.fields = [
    {"name":"Date and Time of Incident","values":["2013-05-13T15:40:00"]},
    {"name":"Reported By","values":["John Doe"]},
    {"name":"Company of Reporter","values":["CompanyA"]}];
```

index.html

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr ngRepeat="field in fields">
      <td>{{data.name}}</td>
      <td>{{data.value}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Is the table data editable?  If so try and use the code below.

```
<td><input type="text" ngModel="field.name" /></td>
<td><input type="text" ngModel="field.name" /></td>
```

Once you have that data, you can manipulate it however you want in the controller or pass it on to a service which would be better.

Comment: how to get text from a cell "name"? e.g. text varies depending on index - Company {{$index}}

Comment: If you're not using Angular's scope, I think you might have to use jQuery to traverse the DOM and get the element that you're looking for.